# What the minimum permission for a local user to get all task schedule no matter who created it

Tags: windows, permissions, schedule

As a local user, I want to get all schedule task no matter who created it. So what kind of permission should this local user have?

**Given:** **Windows 2016**, two users, one is local user, another one is domain administrator

**When:** domain administrator create a schedule named task1, logon as local user, and open 'Task Schedule', cannot see task1.
I try to :

- Add the "full control" permission for "C:\Windows\System32\Tasks" folder to local user, still can not see the task1. But for 2012R2 and 2008R2 it works.
- Add local user to 'local administrator' group it can see the task1. But the permission is too high.

So What is the minimum permission for the local user to see all tasks no matter who created it. (UAC set to never notify)

Comment: The Scheduler COM API supports getting and setting the security on [task folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382560) and [tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382079).

Comment: I created a "\Test" folder and then queried the following SDDL using the API: 'D:AI(A;CIID;FA;;;BA)(A;OIIOID;0x1f019f;;;BA)(A;CIID;FA;;;SY)(A;OIIOID;0x1f019f;;;SY)(A;CIID;FW;;;AU)(A;CIID;FW;;;NS)(A;CIID;FW;;;LS)(A;OICIIOID;FA;;;CO)'. Administrators (BA) and SYSTEM (SY) have all access (FA) to the folder and subfolders (CI), and all read, write and standard access (0x1f019f) for tasks (OI). Authenticated Users (AU), NETWORK SERVICE (NS), and LOCAL SERVICE (LS) have all write (FW) access to the folder and subfolders. CREATOR OWNER (CO) has full control for subfolders and tasks.

Comment: The folder security can be modified to grant read access (FR) for the folder, subfolders, and tasks to all Authenticated Users (AU), or to another group or a specific user.

Comment: Regarding the underlying files/folders in "%SystemRoot%\System32\Tasks", their security is apparently kept in sync upon creation/modification. But changing the file security directly is not reflected in the task security. Via the COM API, I added an entry that grants full control to Users (BU) and then removed this entry from the underlying directory via icacls.exe and rebooted. According to the scheduler API, BU still has full control. It's apparently cached in an "SD" binary value for each task/folder under "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tree".